# Aligning images in a 2x1x2x1x2 format

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to align my images in 2x1x2x1x2 grid format as shown in the image, but then the image repeated but I can't seem to figure out how to get them like this. I'm not really familiar with how grid works, and I can't seem to figure it out. I made them flex, and messed around a bit with position: absolute and stuff but they either get send all the way to the top of my page where my navigation and stuff is. With what I have now the all of the images are stuck to each other which is good but its only in a column.

The code below goes on with a couple more images of the same format.

```css
img {
  width: 50%;
}

#img-layout {
  display: flex;
}

.img-lion {
  float: left;
}

.img-water {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-images">
  <div class="img-lion" id="img-layout">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1459800606415-5B8BDTCZ866H7OTNQMYL/portrait-black.jpg?format=1500w" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-water" id="img-layout">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1452896039354-F8P5FPCM3V9HMWHWZ0FE/main.jpg?format=1000w" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-pedestal" id="img-layout">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1456767403805-KN8Z62OADRLLPKN8YA4P/nytimes-main.jpg?format=1000w" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-berlin" id="img-layout">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1453940592760-5OWKFJCJKG133RHSDOMK/main.jpg?format=1000w" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-dome" id="img-layout">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1452634113588-M32DA4VU1QCEBLOKWCBV/main.jpg?format=1500w" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

So as i said i already messed around with some of the options such as float values, flex proporties but  i just cant seem to figure it out how it works. I looked it up on the internet but i either dont really understand it, or it doesnt seem to work. Hope someone can help ne

Comment: What is a 2x1x2x1x2 grid? I've only ever done 2d layouts, never a 5-dimensional one(!) Also you should switch your IDs and classes - IDs are supposed to be unique - looks like you may have mixed the two up

Comment: uploaded the image now so you can see what i mean. i dont really know how else to explain it

Comment: I highly recommend you look further into CSS grid, as this is exactly the kind of problem it was made for. Have you tried https://cssgridgarden.com/ yet?

Comment: Why have all the divs the same id? why are you applying the flex layout to them and not the container? Why are you mixing flex and float?

Comment: That's normal for someone who is still learning :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly easy to do with grid. I've put in an example below and a comment on each relevant section to explain how it works.

Also each id attribute should be unique.

```css
.container-images {
  /* set up a grid */
  display:grid;
  
  /* tell it that we want 2 columns and each column is equal width */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

img {
  /* make the image fill the entire container then clip the image as best the browser can to fill it */
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container-images > div:nth-child(3n+3) {
  /* every 3rd element start the image at the left hand track but span the two columns */
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-images">
  <div class="img-lion" id="img-layout1">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1459800606415-5B8BDTCZ866H7OTNQMYL/portrait-black.jpg?format=1500w" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-water" id="img-layout2">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1452896039354-F8P5FPCM3V9HMWHWZ0FE/main.jpg?format=1000w" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-pedestal" id="img-layout3">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1456767403805-KN8Z62OADRLLPKN8YA4P/nytimes-main.jpg?format=1000w" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-berlin" id="img-layout4">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1453940592760-5OWKFJCJKG133RHSDOMK/main.jpg?format=1000w" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-dome" id="img-layout5">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1452634113588-M32DA4VU1QCEBLOKWCBV/main.jpg?format=1500w" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-lion" id="img-layout6">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1459800606415-5B8BDTCZ866H7OTNQMYL/portrait-black.jpg?format=1500w" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-water" id="img-layout7">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1452896039354-F8P5FPCM3V9HMWHWZ0FE/main.jpg?format=1000w" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-pedestal" id="img-layout8">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1456767403805-KN8Z62OADRLLPKN8YA4P/nytimes-main.jpg?format=1000w" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-berlin" id="img-layout9">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1453940592760-5OWKFJCJKG133RHSDOMK/main.jpg?format=1000w" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-dome" id="img-layout10">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1452634113588-M32DA4VU1QCEBLOKWCBV/main.jpg?format=1500w" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-lion" id="img-layout11">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1459800606415-5B8BDTCZ866H7OTNQMYL/portrait-black.jpg?format=1500w" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using CSS flex property which is quite simple and easy to deal with:

```css
.container-images {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container-images img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.container-images img:nth-child(3n) {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-images"> 
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1459800606415-5B8BDTCZ866H7OTNQMYL/portrait-black.jpg?format=1500w" alt="" />  
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1452896039354-F8P5FPCM3V9HMWHWZ0FE/main.jpg?format=1000w" alt="" />  
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1456767403805-KN8Z62OADRLLPKN8YA4P/nytimes-main.jpg?format=1000w" alt="" />  
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1453940592760-5OWKFJCJKG133RHSDOMK/main.jpg?format=1000w" alt="" />  
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/563bdd38e4b0283238934c89/1452634113588-M32DA4VU1QCEBLOKWCBV/main.jpg?format=1500w" alt="" />
</div>
```